# kmeans example in matlab does not run

Tags: matlab, statistics, k-means

It is so strange that when I copy and paste the following matlab example

http://www.mathworks.co.jp/help/toolbox/stats/kmeans.html

to the work place and it says:

??? Error using ==> kmeans
Too many input arguments.

Anybody has the same problem?

Comment: works for me. what version of matlab are you using? perhaps you have a function called kmeans in your path, somewhere? what does edit kmeans.m give you?

Comment: i use matlab 7.12.0 r2011a. edit kmeans.m gives me ..\MATLAB\PT-MT\NetLab\kmeans.m file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@carlodsc is right.
Doing `which kmeans`, I can see that my kmeans function is located there:

`/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/toolbox/stats/stats/kmeans.m`

Since yours is located somewhere else, it means that you have another kmean function that is executed.

You should remove it from the path by doing:

`rmpath ..\MATLAB\PT-MT\NetLab`

Answer (score 0):

Ok Oli.
Another or perhaps better solution is increasing the priority of 
the path '...MATLAB/R2011a/toolbox/stats/stats' proportional to other paths containing kmeans. this can be done easily in the 'set path' window.